# How to make new rows and columns based on array value of row Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe with 2 columns:
uid: string
visits: array<structtimestamp:bigint,url:string>

I need to make a new df with 3 columns:
uid | timestamp (timestamp from visits:timestamp)|  url (url from visits: url)

Im kinda new to the scala and spark so i dont have an idea how to map it in the right way.

For example, if i have df like this:

> uid | vists
>
> uid1 | [[timestamp1 : url1, timestamp2: url2]]

I need to make it like this:

> uid | timestamp | url
>
> uid1 | timestamp1 | url1
>
> uid1 | timestamp2| url2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `explode` or `explode_outer` function to explode array columns.

Check below code.

```
scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- uid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- visits: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- url: string (nullable = true)
```

```
scala> df
.withColumn("visits",explode_outer($"visits"))
.select($"uid",$"visits.timestamp".as("timestamp"),$"visits.url")
.show(false)

+---+---------+---+
|uid|timestamp|url|
+---+---------+---+
|uid|111      |url|
+---+---------+---+
```